# Strange errors appearing when trying to execute "/bin/ls -l /usr/include"

Tags: c, shell, runtime-error

So I'm trying to make a shell implementation and it seems to be working just fine. Except there is one very strange issue. I get these errors after I enter the command "/bin/ls -l /usr/include":

Error 1:

> a.out: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top
> (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE &&
> prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) ==
> 0)' failed. Aborted (core dumped)

Error 2:

> realloc(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

char **parse_cmdline( const char *cmdline )
{
int token_count = 1;
for(int i = 0; cmdline[i] != '\0';i++)
{
    if(cmdline[i] == ' ') 
    {
        token_count++;
    }
}
char *token = strtok((char*)cmdline, " ");
char **arr = malloc(token_count+1);
int i;
for(i = 0;token != NULL;i++)
{
    arr[i] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
arr[i] = NULL; // make last element NULL for execvp() to work properly
return arr;
}

int main(void) 
{
int fd = 0; // set read() to read from STDIN_FILENO, because it's number is 0
const size_t read_size = 1; // set chunk size
size_t size = read_size;
char *buff = malloc(size+1);
size_t offset = 0;
size_t res = 0;

write(STDOUT_FILENO, "$ ", strlen("$ "));

while((res = read(fd, buff + offset, read_size)) > 0) // read from stdin and save to buff
{
    if(res == -1)
    {
        //read_error();
        free(buff);
    }
    if(buff[offset] == '\n')
    {
        buff[offset] = '\0';
        char **result = parse_cmdline(buff);
        if(result[0] != NULL)
        {
            int exec;
            int status;
            pid_t pid = fork();

            if(pid == -1)
            {
                //fork_error();
            }
            else if(pid == 0) // Handle child process
            {
                if((exec = execvp(result[0], result)) == -1)
                {
                    //file_error(result[0]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            }

            offset = 0;
            free(buff);
            buff = malloc(size+1);
            size = read_size;
        }
        free(result);
        result = NULL;
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "$ ", strlen("$ "));
    }
    else
    {
        offset += res;
        buff[offset] = '\0';
        if (offset + read_size > size)
        {
            size *= 2;
            buff = realloc(buff, size+1);
        }
    }
}
free(buff);
return 0;
}
```

**Here is how to reproduce Error 1:**
Start the program and the first input should be: "/bin/ls -l /usr/include". After that press enter, and after that enter any command or just a blank line and the error will appear.

**How to reproduce Error 2:**
Start the program and run any commands. Then run "/bin/ls -l /usr/include" and then run 2 other commands and the error will appear.

Note: Working with Oracle VM VirtualBox, compiling with:

gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c11 file.c

./a.out

Comment: Edit your question to provide a [mre], including a **complete** program that other people can compile without change or addition and execute to reproduce the problem. Do not post text as images. It is unnecessary to include all the text you did to show the problem; you just need a few lines showing the command executed and the results, and you can mark the text with `<pre>` and `</pre>` to format it.

Comment: Okay, done, is it good now?

Comment: No. Read the information about providing a [mre]. For this issue, you should provide **one** piece of code, not separate “my code” and “main”, that reproduces the issue, and **it should be ready-to-compile code**. That means it has `#include <stdio.h>`, `int main(int argc, char *argv[]`, and all the other parts needed to compile. Make it easy for other people to debug; do not make people who are voluntarily supplying information and labor have to do extra work.

Comment: `char **arr = malloc(token_count+1);` hmm, count+1 bytes? I'm afraid pointers are larger than one byte, try `(token_count+1)*sizeof(arr[0])` or something.

Comment: @dratenik That fixed it, thanks! I would've never seen that I thought it was a problem with the freeing of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char **arr = malloc(token_count+1);` does not allocate enough space. Because not enough space is allocated, attempting to fill it with `token_count+1` pointers overruns the allocated space and corrupts other data in memory.

`malloc` allocates a number of bytes, not a number of elements. It does not know the size of the elements you are trying to allocate. So you must always tell it how many total bytes to allocate. You can do this by multiplying the number of things you want to allocate by the size of each thing.

A general pattern that works for `malloc` is:

```
SomeType *p = malloc(NumberOfThings * sizeof *p);
```

That works because `*p` is one of the objects that the memory will contain, and `sizeof *p` produces the number of bytes that such an object requires. So in this case you can use:

```
char **arr = malloc((token_count+1) * sizeof *arr);
```